# How to implement several url in the same store sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2, store

Im trying to create an app of news rss , respecting the mvc architecture , i create a store file for the home page ,but i need for each category an url , is there a way to put many urls in the same store ? or do i have to create for each category a store file ?

```
 //The home store
 Ext.define("MyApp2.store.NewsStore", {
 extend: "Ext.data.Store",
 requires: ["Ext.data.proxy.JsonP", "Ext.dataview.List", "MyApp2.model.News"         ,"Ext.data.reader.Xml"],
  config: {
model: "MyApp2.model.News",
autoLoad: true,
proxy: {
    type: 'jsonp',
    url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=%20select%20*%20from%20rss%20where%20url%20%3D%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.aufaitmaroc.com%2Ffeeds%2Fmaroc.xml%22&format=json',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'query.results.item'
        }
    }


}    
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for separate store for each class because model will be same for all RSS feeds, you can build your `proxy` using whichever url you want and use store's [setProxy](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-setProxy) method to set this proxy to store before calling load method.

Another way to do this is to create store with custom proxy(based on user interaction) when user tap/swipe on the category and set the store to the list/dataview you use to display entries.

Comment: Thank you !i'll try the first one :)

Comment: Can u plz give me an example?